# Why i don't have the property Items on listView1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When adding files to the listView1 in this method i do have the property Items.

```
private void AddFiles(string strPath)
    {       
        listView1.BeginUpdate();

        listView1.Items.Clear();
        iFiles = 0;
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(strPath + "\\");           
            FileInfo[] theFiles = di.GetFiles();            
            foreach(FileInfo theFile in theFiles)
            {
                iFiles++;
                ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(theFile.Name);
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(theFile.Length.ToString());
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(theFile.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString());
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(theFile.LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString());
                listView1.Items.Add(lvItem);                                    
            }
        }
        catch(Exception Exc)    {   statusBar1.Text = Exc.ToString();   }

        listView1.EndUpdate();      
    }
```

But now i want to add properties so when i'm doing mouse right click on a file it will show a contextmenu:

```
private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            int index = listView1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (index != ListBox.NoMatches)
            {
                listJobs.SelectedIndex = index;

                Job job = (Job)listJobs.Items[index];

                ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();


                AddMenuItem(cm, "Run", QueueForRun, job).Enabled = !job.Pending;
                AddMenuItem(cm, "Cancel run", CancelQueueForRun, job).Enabled = (job.State == JobState.Pending || job.State == JobState.Running);
                AddMenuItem(cm, "Open folder", OpenFolder, job);

                cm.Show(listJobs, e.Location);
            }
        }
    }
```

This time i don't have IndexFromPoint and also not Items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `IndexFromPoint()` is a `ListBox` method, `ListView` has not. In `ListView` there is `GetItemAt()` method to achieve same result.

```
var item = listView.GetItemAt(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
if (item != null) {
    listJobs.SelectedIndex = item.Index; // Assuming listJobs is a ListBox
}
```

**EDIT**: according to your comment if `listJobs` is a `ListView` too then it has not `SelectedIndex` but it has `SelectedIndices`, simply:

```
listJobs.SelectedIndices.Clear();
listJobs.SelectedIndices.Add(item.Index);
```

You have first to clear the list because, by default, `MultiSelect` is `true` then you may select multiple items.

Comment: Adriano in my code all the places listJobs should be listView1 it was my mistake listJobs should be listView1 in all places. So listView dosen't have also SlectedIndex.